# Subgroup generated by the natural numbers

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we have a set $G$ and consider $G$ to be the set of integers. We know that $(G,+)$ is a group. So far so good.

However, I read that this group G is generated by the set of natural numbers.

How can that be?

For example, how can we obtain $-1$ from the natural numbers with the addition?

Does this holds for the multiplication?

Comment: Given a group $G$ and a subset $A\subset G$, the subgroup generated by $A$ is the smallest (by inclusion) subgroup of $G$ that contains $A$. It is also the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ that contain $A$. If $G$ are the integers with $+$, and $A$ are the natural numbers. Then since $n\in A$, then $-n$ must belong to any subgroup containing $A$.

Comment: My guess is that you are thinking of the subgroup generated by a subset as all sums of elements of the subset. That is almost right, except that one also need to consider their inverses. So, sums of the elements of the subset and their inverses.

Comment: So $-1$ don’t belong to the natural numbers, but they are in some subgroup containing the natural numbers?

Comment: Yes, just by definition. It is in *all* subgroups containing the natural numbers or just containing $1$.

Comment: Yes, in facto I was thinking that the subgroup generated by the natural numbers would be all the sums of the elements of that subset, but by thinking in this way we wouldn’t have subgroup because they would not have inverse

Comment: If $A$ is a subset of $(G,+)$, the subgroup generated by $A$ is the set $\{\pm a_1 \pm a_2 \pm \dots \pm a_n | a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \in A\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considering this problem and some of the suggestions in the comments, I realize that:

When we are talking about the the **subgroup generated by the set of all natural numbers**, we are talking about the **least subgroup that contains the set of all natural numbers**.

So it means that the subgroup generated by the natural numbers **contains the set of those numbers**, **plus an identity** (which for addition is $0$), **plus they’re inverse** (which are all the negative numbers).

And we clearly see that this subgroup is the **set of integers with the addition**.